How to map POJO with String id to MongoDB document with ObjectId id using @BsonRepresentation
I have a collection, Users, in a MongoDB database. Each document has an _id of type ObjectId. I would like to be able to map these into a POJO which has an id of type String in my application.
Currently, the User POJO in my application has an ObjectId like so.
@BsonId
private ObjectId id;

The 'POJO Customization' page in the MongoDB docs says that I should be able to do the following:
@BsonId
@BsonRepresentation(BsonType.OBJECT_ID)
private String id;

But it still results in the following error:
Failed to decode 'User'. Decoding '_id' errored with: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID.
This is the code used for retrieving the User from the database.
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    MongoClient mongo = mongoClientProvider.getMongoClient();
    MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("ct6049DB");
    collection = db.getCollection("users", User.class);
}

// Get a user by their email
public User getUserByEmail(String email) {
    return collection.find(eq("email", email)).first();
}

The CodecRegistry used on my MongoClient is:
CodecRegistry myRegistry = fromRegistries(
    MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),             
    fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
);

But I have also tried adding Conventions.ANNOTATION_CONVENTION to this.
I should specify that changing the id on the POJO to be ObjectId rather than a String (as specified in the answer here: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID) is not an option. The other answers on the linked question suggest removing all documents in my collection that have an ObjectId for id (also not an option), adding @BsonId (which I already have), and adding @BsonProperty("id") (which does not fix the issue, and neither does adding @BsonProperty("_id")).
This is for a project demonstrating the differences between SQL and NoSQL databases, so it would be nice for the POJOs to be database agnostic (String for id) while also maintaining MongoDB's preferred id type within the database.

For usage of mongoDB you can use like this :
String id annoted with like @Id. Mongo automatic consider it as a objectId. This will work for MongoDB

@DevVaghasiya when I replace @BsonId with @Id, I no longer get the error, but instead the id field is just left as null when getting items from the database

Can you edit your question and add the portion how you get from data from database?

@DevVaghasiya I've added it. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Fixed. Just needed to maven clean before starting Glassfish configuration.

I am providing the structure of code for Java.
@Data
@Document("users")
public class User {

    @Id
    String id;

    @SearchField
    String firstName;
}

Then after,
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String> {

}

This repository help you get data from mongo.
Then after,
This is the serivce code
User find();

Then after,
It is the service implementation which implements the service class and annotate with @Service annotation.
@Autowired

UserRepository userRepository;

    public User find() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
        }

Then after the last Controller part,
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController{
  @Autowired
UserService userService;
@RequestMapping(name="getUser",  value="/getUser",  method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Response<User> getUserById(){
    return Response.ok().setData(userService.find()).setMessage("YOUR_RESPONSE_MESSAGE");
  }
}

My Response class,
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response<T> {

    private Status status;
    private T data;
    private String message;
}

This whole process start from controller (response inside it) > service > service implementation > repo > model (pojo).
hope you understand.

Thank you for your answer. I probably should have also specified in my question that I am not using Spring. My current controller and service structure works fine - the problem only occurs when I change ObjectId to String in my POJO model. I specifically want to know why the @BsonRepresentation(BsonType.OBJECT_ID) is not working as it is described here
